# Automatically generated makefile in Eclipse C/C++ gives compiling of only one module

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, makefile

so as the topic states -  Automatically generated makefile in Eclipse C/C++ gives compiling only one module... I have an Eclipse project in C/C++ which compiles with MinGW (gcc). Now I want to make it build-able from command line with makefile. So I have checked that makefiles(Makefile, objects.mk, sources.mk and all subdir.mk-s) are obtained. The problem is when I type and run make in a proper directory (containing Makefile) it compiles only one file, in this particular case des.c (which gives one object file des.o) and exits without any errors I don't know why. Whilst building from eclipse successfully gives an executable as artefact.

Apologizing about the bunch of the attachments to this question - though I think it is all relevant.

[image: Toolcahin Settings]

[image: C/C++ Build Properties, automatically generated makefile]
Here it exists after compiling on file
[image: Here it exists after compiling on file]
Here is a Makefile:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include sim/xyssl/subdir.mk
-include sim/subdir.mk
-include hal_i386/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: my_sim_card.exe

# Tool invocations
my_sim_card.exe: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: MinGW C++ Linker'
    g++  -o "my_sim_card.exe" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(CC_DEPS)$(C++_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(OBJS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS)$(CXX_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(C_DEPS) my_sim_card.exe
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

I have also tried commenting first include of subdir (namely include sim/xyssl/subdir.mk) in this case it compiles only STK_application.c like here
[image]
Maybe it is relevant to the issue reason - I have mounted files/folders as external ones (upper level folders out of workspace dir), but - again - it works in Eclipse ok. Also I want to say that it behaves the same irrespectively whether the option `Expand Env. Variable Refs in Makefile` enabled or disabled.
Other files look like:
sources.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

C_UPPER_SRCS := 
CXX_SRCS := 
C++_SRCS := 
OBJ_SRCS := 
CC_SRCS := 
ASM_SRCS := 
CPP_SRCS := 
C_SRCS := 
S_UPPER_SRCS := 
O_SRCS := 
CC_DEPS := 
C++_DEPS := 
EXECUTABLES := 
OBJS := 
C_UPPER_DEPS := 
CXX_DEPS := 
CPP_DEPS := 
C_DEPS := 

# Every subdirectory with source files must be described here
SUBDIRS := \
hal_i386 \
. \
sim \
sim/xyssl \
```

subdir.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
C_SRCS += \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl/des.c 

OBJS += \
./sim/xyssl/des.o 

C_DEPS += \
./sim/xyssl/des.d 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
sim/xyssl/des.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl/des.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

subdir.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
C_SRCS += \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/STK_application.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/aes.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/auth_comp128.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/auth_comp128_v23.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/auth_gost.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_2G.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_3G.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_adm.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_auth.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_network_auth.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_toolkit.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/fs.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/fstream.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/milenage.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/sim_access.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/sim_toolkit.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/sw.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/t0.c \
C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/tools.c 

OBJS += \
./sim/STK_application.o \
./sim/aes.o \
./sim/auth_comp128.o \
./sim/auth_comp128_v23.o \
./sim/auth_gost.o \
./sim/commands_2G.o \
./sim/commands_3G.o \
./sim/commands_adm.o \
./sim/commands_auth.o \
./sim/commands_network_auth.o \
./sim/commands_toolkit.o \
./sim/fs.o \
./sim/fstream.o \
./sim/milenage.o \
./sim/sim_access.o \
./sim/sim_toolkit.o \
./sim/sw.o \
./sim/t0.o \
./sim/tools.o 

C_DEPS += \
./sim/STK_application.d \
./sim/aes.d \
./sim/auth_comp128.d \
./sim/auth_comp128_v23.d \
./sim/auth_gost.d \
./sim/commands_2G.d \
./sim/commands_3G.d \
./sim/commands_adm.d \
./sim/commands_auth.d \
./sim/commands_network_auth.d \
./sim/commands_toolkit.d \
./sim/fs.d \
./sim/fstream.d \
./sim/milenage.d \
./sim/sim_access.d \
./sim/sim_toolkit.d \
./sim/sw.d \
./sim/t0.d \
./sim/tools.d 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
sim/STK_application.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/STK_application.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/aes.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/aes.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/auth_comp128.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/auth_comp128.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/auth_comp128_v23.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/auth_comp128_v23.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/auth_gost.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/auth_gost.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/commands_2G.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_2G.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/commands_3G.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_3G.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/commands_adm.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_adm.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/commands_auth.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_auth.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/commands_network_auth.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_network_auth.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/commands_toolkit.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/commands_toolkit.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/fs.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/fs.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/fstream.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/fstream.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/milenage.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/milenage.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/sim_access.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/sim_access.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/sim_toolkit.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/sim_toolkit.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/sw.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/sw.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/t0.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/t0.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

sim/tools.o: C:/Users/ruslan/Downloads/SIM/1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/tools.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -DMIN_GW -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/hal_i386" -I"C:\Users\ruslan\Downloads\SIM\workspace.mingw../../1.USIM_sources/trunk/sim/xyssl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

**EDIT:** I have also tried building with GNU32 Make tool besides MinGW Make - the same problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run make all instead of just make.

If you run make without any target it will default to the first target mentioned in the makefile, which in this case is sim/xyssl/des.o. When you run the makefile from Eclipse I suspect that it actually runs make all.

Comment: That was the trick, `make all` worked for me, well done, thanks.